# Entity Framework 4.3 Windows Azure Keyword not supported: 'metadata'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure

My Code works locally, with connection string pointing to AZURE SQL SERVER. But as soon as i publish to Azure Web Site every View with EF Model throws this error.
I have change the " to ' as one of the proposed solutions, nothing works.
Im stuck!!

```
  System.Data.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on ConnectionString. ---> System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'metadata'.
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)
```

Comment: Please post the connection string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have **MultipleActiveResultSets=True** in your connection string then please **remove** it and the same connection string should work in Windows Azure. I found this being most common error in your situation.

If that is not the case, please post your connection string and I will take a look.

Comment: Setting it to False did not work, but REMOVING it Solved it!!! Any insight on why this happens and is it related to Azure?

Comment: Mostly because the runtime on Windows Azure does not recognize it properly and cause this error. It answer solved your problem, glad if you please accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as the OP, but his solution didn't work for me.

It was a connection string issue, but not with the quotes.

Since it took me two days to resolve, maybe this will help someone else:

The connection string that works *[for my ASP.NET MVC 4.5/Entity Framework 5.0 application when hosted on Azure (I develop against SQL Server 2012 locally, but migrate the database to Azure SQL Database (using the [SQL Database Migration Wizard](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/))). I'm using database first to create my .edmx file (I generate the (data) model from the database)]* is:

```
<add name="MYPROJECTENTITIES" connectionString="**metadata=**res://*/MODELS.MYPROJECTMODEL.csdl|res://*/MODELS.MYPROJECTMODEL.ssdl|res://*/MODELS.MYPROJECTMODEL.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=tcp:B6JD5K5EP4.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=MYPROJECT_DB;Integrated Security=False;User ID=MYPROJECT@B6JD5K5EP4;Password=MYPASSWORDABC123;**MultipleActiveResultSets=True**;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

The text in UPPERCASE is my Azure information. Obviously, you'll need to use your own instead.

This part of the connection string gave me nightmares, and it could be causing your issue as well:

```
res://*/Models.MyProjectModel.csdl|res://*/Models.MyProjectModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.MyProjectModel.msl
```

*Those references have to be exactly right*. Let me repeat: *Those references have to be exactly right!!*

After reading [this article from 2008](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/08/13/38628/) ("Troubleshooting Entity Framework Connection Strings"), I used .NET Reflector to look inside the MyProjectModel.dll (the name of my .dll (likely different in your project) like he suggests and, sure enough, the connection string (that was generated automatically for me by the Entity Framework!) was wrong. It didn't include a prefix. As soon as I added **Models.** prefix (which is how the .csdl/.msl/.ssdl are named inside of my .dll (likely different in yours)), everything worked great. Have a look inside your .dll and see if the names match. If not, change them to match what appears in the .dll. (Read the article above if what I'm saying isn't clear enough.)

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the connection string type to Custom in Azure portal.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer on another SO thread that might be helpful. Steps I have mentioned there include an end-to-end configuration of connection string on Azure and dynamically using it. And yes, it fixes the error in question!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37938912/3785895

**More Info:** Along with changing the providerName, there are a few extra bits we might need to check. Azure seems to be updating the web.config file after publishing the API App/Web App.