# Windows Azure portal connection strings

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

couple of questions regarding the connection strings section for websites in the windows azure portal:

do the settings in the portal take precedence over what's in web.config?  If so, should I not include connection strings in the web.config file?  Are the settings in the portal sometimes referred to as app.config?

can i set connection strings for ado.net entities in the windows azure portal?  This does not seem to work for this specific type of connection string.

in the portal i included the following connection string and gave it the same name as what is in my web.config:

metadata=res://*/Models.TABLENAME.csdl|res://*/Models.TABLENAME.ssdl|res://*/Models.TABLENAME.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="Server=tcp:SERVERNAME.database.windows.net;Database=DATABASENAME;User ID=USER;Password=PASSWORD;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;

The connection string in my web.config file works in my dev environment, but i think i have something typed wrong on the azure portal.

Comment: is this for an Azure Website or WebRole?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782337/retrieve-and-use-windows-azures-connection-strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"do the settings in the portal take precedence over what's in web.config?"
**Yes.**

"If so, should I not include connection strings in the web.config file? "
**Use the connectionstring found in Azure portal and insert it in your web.config.
This, of course, does not apply to if you are using a local database. Then you should use the local connectionsstring.**

"Are the settings in the portal sometimes referred to as app.config?"
**No. Not if you are stil on the subject of connectionstrings.**

"can i set connection strings for ado.net entities in the windows azure portal? This does not seem to work for this specific type of connection string"
**Check my blog post on basic set up for this here under step 2(2. Now, go to the Management portal and Create a new db.) http://geekswithblogs.net/MagnusKarlsson/archive/2012/10/31/add-sql-azure-database-to-azure-web-role-and-persist.aspx**

Comment: thanks mate.  very helpful information.  i'm new to mvc and most of its parts.