# Retrieve the connection string of an SQL Azure database that is linked to a Windows Azure Web Site with C#.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

The configuration page of a Windows Azure Web Site has a "connection strings" section. The section lists connection strings for linked resources. How do we programmatically retrieve the connection string for a linked SQL Azure Database?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Solution**

Programmatically retrieve the connection string as follows:

```
connString = 
    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PREFIX_myConnStringName");
```

**Explaination**

The Azure connection strings become environmental variables. [Documentation](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/web-sites/how-to-configure-websites/#howtoconfigSQL) explains that Azure creates the variables with the [prefixes](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/best-practices/troubleshooting-web-sites/) as follows:

> SQL Server: SQLCONNSTR_myConnStringName
>
> MySQL: MYSQLCONNSTR_myConnStringName
>
> SQL Database: SQLAZURECONNSTR_myConnStringName
>
> Custom: CUSTOMCONNSTR_myConnStringName
>
> SQL Azure: SQLAZURECONNSTR_myConnStringName

Knowing that, we can retrieve the desired connection string with the following code:

```
connString = 
    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SQLAZURECONNSTR_myConnStringName");
```

**Other Option**

As another option, this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782337/retrieve-and-use-windows-azures-connection-strings) about how to access the connection string through web.config as follows:

```
<add name="myConnStringName" 
    connectionString="you can leave this blank"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Note: we might not have to include the providerName attribute.

**Further Research**

We can view all the available environmental variables and connection strings by putting this code into a Razor view. Warning: this will reveal your password!

```
<ul>
    @foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry ev in Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables())
    {
        if (ev.Value.ToString().ToLower().Contains("data source"))
        {
            <li><strong>@ev.Key.ToString()</strong> @ev.Value.ToString()</li>
        }
    }
</ul>

<ul>
    @foreach (System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings cs in System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
    {
        <li><strong>@cs.Name</strong> @cs.ConnectionString</li>
    }
</ul>
```

That's all for now.

Comment: See also: [How to use an Environment variable in an Azure Resource Management Template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43124084/how-to-use-an-environment-variable-in-an-azure-resource-management-template)

Comment: About your "other option": if I include that snippet in my web.config file, how will I be able to debug my app locally? I ask this because in that case, the connection strings will never be specified except on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the connection string as an environmental variable this way would seem to be the wrong way. You would define it under the connection string and then just call GetConnectionString from the IConfiguration interface, without making it more complex and prefixing with database strings.

Try the below this makes it much simpler

```
IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();

var connection = _config.GetConnectionString("DatabaseConnection");
```