# Accessing connection strings in Azure using Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable() while debugging localhost

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to set up my WebAPI project to dynamically grab the correct connection string depending on what environment the project is deployed to in Azure. I used the following Stack Overflow post as an example of sorts:
[Accessing SqlServer conn strings in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507956/retrieve-the-connection-string-of-an-sql-azure-database-that-is-linked-to-a-wind)

In my code, I'm trying to set this value, but it's coming back null.

```
private static readonly string _connStr =
    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SQLAZURECONNSTR_conn");
```

And in my web.config, the connection string is stored as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="conn" connectionString="{Connection string stuff}" />
</connectionStrings>
```

In my deployment location up on Azure, I set the connection string in the `Application Settings` section of my app service. My problem is that while testing locally, my connection string value isn't getting set in the aforementioned line of code `_connStr`.

I was made to understand that I didn't need to add the `SQLAZURECONNSTR_` segment in my `web.config` and that the `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()` would detect the environment, then grab the correct connection string. I'm beginning to suspect that is incorrect though. Am I missing something? I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misunderstood how the settings work.

To get the setting you should use

```
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;
```

Azure will change the setting on the fly to whatever you set there. *In addition*, it also sets an environment variable called SQLAZURECONNSTR_conn. But this will not be set in your local environment unless you set it. The setting itself won't create it.

And since this is a connection string, be sure to set it in the Web App's **Connection Strings** section, not App Settings!