# "Keyword not Supported" Error message while fetching connection string from azure application setting using environment variable

Tags: c#, azure, web-config, environment-variables, azure-application-settings

I am trying to get the connection string from **Azure Application settings** using **environment variables**, But it seems that the format of the connection string that I am putting in Azure App setting is not proper.Here is my original connection string that works fine in localhost.

```
    <add connectionString="Server=tcp:****.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=***;
Persist Security Info=False;User ID=******;Password=*********;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;
    Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=1200000;
    Max Pool Size=500;Pooling=true;" name="Con_String"></add>
```

I am putting `"Server=tcp:****.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=****;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=****;Password=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=1200000;Max Pool Size=500;Pooling=true;"`as the **con_string** value in [Azure Application Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfygF.png)

Now for fetching the Connection string at runtime I am using Environment variable as string `ConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SQLAZURECONNSTR_Con_String");`

But  during running the web app I am getting the exception message **Keyword not supported: '"Server'.**

I tried the approaches in 
[Retrieve and use Windows Azure's connection strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782337/retrieve-and-use-windows-azures-connection-strings) and other similar posts ,but didn't work. Am I missing something silly here?

Comment: When you entered the value in application settings, did you include the double quotes (`"`) as well? If that's the case, can you try by removing them? So the value you will enter would be `Server=tcp:****.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=****;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=****;Password=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=1200000;Max Pool Size=500;Pooling=true;` (without starting and ending double quotes).

Comment: @GauravMantri I tried it and It's giving a different exception message **The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.**

Comment: Please have a try to use the following code. `ConnectionString =ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Con_String"].ConnectionString`. According to your supplied screenshot.   `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SQLAZURECONNSTR_Con_String")` should work.

Comment: Thanks @GauravMantri. Removing the double quotes worked for me,Actually I had forget to save the Appsetting after the change.Sorry for the immature previous reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I missing something silly here?

If you still get the `Keyword not supported: '"Server'` or `The ConnectionString property has not been initialized`.

I assume that you **don't save the appsetting** after you add the connection string the WebApp appseting.

[image]

The following code are both working on my side.

```
ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Con_String"].Connec‌​tionString.

ConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SQLAZURECONNSTR_Con_Stri‌​ng")
```

Test Result:

[image]

**Note**: as GauravMantri mentioned that there is no need quotes (") in the connection string in the Azure WebApp appsetting.

Comment: Seriously It was a very SILLY mistake from me! Actually GauravMantri's suggestion was perfect. and What you mentioned that I had forget to save the webApp setting. Thanks a ton to both of you as it has solved my headache of 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

In my case issue was connected with the stupid mistake: when *copy/pasted* connection string to `Notepad++` I somehow missed that newline operator appeared because of the `Notepad++` was wrapping the text or smth else.

In any case, I've copy/pasted to `Notepad` then replaced `User ID` and `Password`, then copy/pasted again to the server, Saved the settings then Restarted the server.
Finally, issue fixed.